# Dynamic hide select list on safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, safari

Perhaps I'm doing it wrong, but here is the behavior I'm implementing on a select element :

I've created a page with several `<select>` and custom them with a stylesheet.
For a particular one, I've added after it a `div` with style `position: absolute;`, which displays a list with check boxes, allowing a multiple selection.
This `<select>` have a unic `<option>` - its aim is to display a title like "Select your options".
To display my customized list and not the options list, according to the mains browsers compatibility, I had to implement a `onclick`function like this :

```
function showList(input,sIdTarget)
{
    //hide the dropdown list, compatible with all browser
    $(input).css({ "display": "none" }).blur().css({"display": "" });
    $("#"+sIdTarget).css("display","");
}
```

I still have an issue with Safari. Calling this function on the `onclick` event trigger it after an element of the list is clicked.

Here is a sample : https://jsfiddle.net/L6uhkg9h/1/

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using JQuery to hide the dropdown list after the user's selected it, you can disable the dropdown list and attach the click handler to the parent DIV instead. Setting a `pointer-events: none` style on the `select` element will prevent that element from responding to any click events. You can then attach the click handler to `.customSelect`:

```
$('.customSelect').on('click.selectList', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  if($("#listeSecteurs").css("display") === "none")
    $("#listeSecteurs").css("display","");
  else
    $("#listeSecteurs").css("display","none");
});
```

When the user clicks the `.customSelect` DIV, you'll toggle whether or not `#listeSecteurs` is displayed. When the user clicks on anything other than `#listSecteurs`, you want to get rid of `#listSecteurs`, so you attach a click handler to `window` to do this:

```
$(window).on('click.selectListWindow', function(e) {
      $("#listeSecteurs").css({"display":"none"});
});
```

Note that `e.stopPropagation()` in the `.customSelect` handler will prevent this window click handler from being triggered when the `.customSelect` div is clicked.  You also need to stop click events from propagating from `.hideableSelectList` to `window`, because when the user clicks the former, you want to keep `#listSecteurs` displayed.

```
$('.hideableSelectList').on('click.selectList', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Putting it all together:

```html
<html>
  <head>
  <style>
  .customSelect{
    width: calc(100% - 2px);
    background-color: white; 
    border: solid 1px #AAAAAA;
    border-top-width: 2px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 2px;            
}     
.customSelect select{
    width: 100%; 
    padding: 5px 8px;
    border: 0px;        
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    overflow:hidden; 
}
.customSelect select.collapse{
    background: transparent url('https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-arrow-down-b-128.png') no-repeat; 
    background-size: 10px;
    background-position: right 10px center;
}
.customSelect select.expanded{
    background: transparent url('https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/flat-ui-icons-24-px/24/cross-24-128.png') no-repeat; 
    background-size: 10px;
    background-position: right 10px center;
}
.hideableSelectList{
    position: relative;    
}
.hideableSelectList div{
    background-color: white;
    max-height: 300px;
    width: 250px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0px 10px;
    border: solid 1px #C0C0C0;
    z-index: 3;
}
  </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="customSelect" style="width: 195px;">
    <select class="collapse" style="width: 195px; z-index: 0; pointer-events: none" >
        <option style="height: 0px">-&nbsp;Select your options&nbsp;-</option>
    </select><br>
    <div class="hideableSelectList" style="z-index: 10;">
        <div id="listeSecteurs" style="display: none; left: 0px;">
          <ul style="list-style-type: none;">
            <li><input type="checkbox">val 1</li>
            <li><input type="checkbox">val 2</li>
            <li><input type="checkbox">val 3</li>
            <li><input type="checkbox">val 4</li>
            <li><input type="checkbox">val 5</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
  </body>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>

  $(function () {

    $('.hideableSelectList').on('click.selectList', function(e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
    });

    $('.customSelect').on('click.selectList', function(e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
      if($("#listeSecteurs").css("display") === "none")
        $("#listeSecteurs").css("display","");
      else
        $("#listeSecteurs").css("display","none");
    });

    $(window).on('click.selectListWindow', function(e) {
          $("#listeSecteurs").css({"display":"none"});
    });
  });

  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: this won't solve the problem with the keyboard navigation, if you press `alt+arrow down/up` the option still shows, also with the drop-down open.

Comment: @deblocker, That's an excellent point, and your solution is superior if one expects some users to be using keyboard navigation.

Comment: no worries, i am still convinced that there isn't an exact solution, only workarounds. I'm just truly interested in this topic, How do you would solve the issue with the keyboard? It would be nice, if you could find some time to  share an idea about that.

Answer (score 1):

Restyle the `select option` in a cross-browser way is really hard, if not almost impossible.

If you need to keep the highest possible cross-browser compatibility, and already have a custom styled option drop-down, what you need now is the focusable and tabbable part of the select.

In my following proposal instead of a `select` i'm using an `input button` to allow mouse and keyboard navigation among forms elements and avoid the styling (drop-down) and behavior (click, focus events) issues related to the different browser-specific implementation of the `select`.

The `input button` will maintain the native focus behavior and provide the same focus shadow as all other form elements in Safari and the dotted border in other browsers (FF, Chrome, IE and so on).

Regarding keyboard and mouse navigation, you still need to have some global handlers, as your custom drop-down part shall be handled in code.

In my proposal you will find also an example of keyboard navigation among the `checkboxes` inside your drop-down, which is handling also the case of hidden and/or disabled elements.

```js
function toggleSelectList(el) {
  var customSelect = $(el).closest(".customSelect");
  if (customSelect.length > 0) {
    if ($(el).hasClass("customSelectFocus")) {
      if ($(customSelect).children(".customSelectList").css("display") === "none") {
        clickSelectFocus(customSelect);
        blurSelectFocus(customSelect);
      } else {
        hideSelectList(customSelect);
        focusSelectFocus(customSelect)
      }
    } else {
      // mouse down inside custom drop down list
    }
  } else {
    // mouse down outside any custom select
    hideAllSelectLists();
  }
}

function handleSelectNavigation(e, key) {
  var customSelect = $(".customSelectList").filter(":visible").closest(".customSelect");
  var all = $(".customSelectList input:visible:enabled");
  var first = all[0], last = all[all.length - 1], current = $(".customSelectList input:focus");
  var currentIndex = $(all).index(current);
  switch (key) {
    case 9: // tab
      if(e.shiftKey == 1) {
        if ($(first).is(":focus")) {
          e.preventDefault();
          $(last).focus();
        }
      } else {
        if ($(last).is(":focus")) {
          e.preventDefault();
          $(first).focus();
        }        
      }
      break;
    case 13: // enter
      toggleSelectList(e.target);
      break
    case 27: // escape
      hideAllSelectLists();
      focusSelectFocus(customSelect);
      break
    case 38: // up arrow
      $(first).is(":focus") ? $(last).focus() : $(all)[currentIndex - 1].focus();
      break
    case 40: // down arrow
      $(last).is(":focus") ? $(first).focus() : $(all)[currentIndex + 1].focus();
  }
}

$(document).on("mousedown", function(e) {
  toggleSelectList(e.target);
});

$(document).on("keydown", function(e) {
  var key = e.charCode ? e.charCode : e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : 0;
  var cases = [9, 13, 27, 38, 40];
  if ($.inArray(key, cases) > -1) handleSelectNavigation(e, key);
});

function setSelectLabel(customSelect) {
  var numSelected = $(customSelect).children(".customSelectList").find("input:checked").length;
  var text = (numSelected === 0) ? "- Select your options -" : " %1 option(s) selected".replace("%1", numSelected);
  $(customSelect).find(".customSelectFocus").val(text);
}

function focusSelectFocus(customSelect) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $(customSelect).find(".customSelectFocus").focus();
  }, 0);
}

function blurSelectFocus(customSelect) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    var firstInput = $(customSelect).find(".customSelectList input:visible:enabled").first();
    var selectFocus = $(customSelect).find(".customSelectFocus").first();
    firstInput.length > 0 ? $(firstInput).focus() : $(selectFocus).blur();
  }, 0);
}

function clickSelectFocus(customSelect) {
  $(".customSelect").not(customSelect).each(function() {
    hideSelectList(this); // hiding all other than the one clicked
  });
  if ($(customSelect).children(".customSelectList").css("display") === "none") {
    showSelectList(customSelect);
  } else {
    hideSelectList(customSelect);
  }
}

function showSelectList(customSelect) {
  $(customSelect).children(".customSelectList").css("display", "");
  $(customSelect).find(".customSelectFocus").addClass("expanded").removeClass("collapse");
}

function hideSelectList(customSelect) {
  $(customSelect).children(".customSelectList").css("display", "none");
  $(customSelect).find(".customSelectFocus").addClass("collapse").removeClass("expanded");
  setSelectLabel(customSelect);
}

function hideAllSelectLists() {
  $(".customSelect").each(function() {
    hideSelectList(this);
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".customSelect").each(function() {
    setSelectLabel(this);
  });
  $(".customSelect input[type=checkbox]").change(function() {
    setSelectLabel($(this).closest(".customSelect"));
  });
  focusSelectFocus($(".customSelect").first());
});
```

```css
.customSelect {
  width: 195px;
  margin-left: -5px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 0 none transparent;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.customSelectBox {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid #AAAAAA;
}

.customSelectFocus {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 0 none transparent;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
  -moz-border-radius: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.customSelectFocus.collapsed {
  background: white url("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAAKCAYAAACNMs+9AAAAB3RJTUUH4QUIDC0RXxhGYQAAAAlwSFlzAAALEwAACxMBAJqcGAAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAA1SURBVHjaY2AYcHAFiP/jwJeRFSoB8Qssil5A5VCAARB/RFIEYuvjcoIdEL+DYtuBDg8oAACLqxRIufkW/wAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==") no-repeat;
  background-size: 10px;
  background-position: right 10px center;
  background-position: top 10px right 6px;
  background-position-x: 178px;
  background-position-y: 8px;
}

.customSelectFocus.expanded {
  background: white url("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAAKCAYAAACNMs+9AAAAB3RJTUUH4QUIDCwtaWwLpwAAAAlwSFlzAABOIAAATiABFn2Z3gAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAACESURBVHjaZZBBCoMwEEUHD2Ndil3b64veQN3ZlSktinGlYP/IDIxj4EGS/xJ+QkT0ABXI6T4uWQ0OMDo5BYNkHW88wcfJVprBS0+zHCT4ygGeT1bSUYCfCEwEpYaJEVewmfUOFn9bZjpF6XV7IEtv06mUGsHLjZNsZ/2NVjd6J9nfOLM/MU0xq4g4dtgAAAAASUVORK5CYII=") no-repeat;
  background-size: 10px;
  background-position: right 10px center;
  background-position: top 10px right 6px;
  background-position-x: 178px;
  background-position-y: 8px;
}

.customSelectList {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  font: -webkit-small-control;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: "MS Shell Dlg \32";
  font-weight: 400;
}

.customSelectList div {
  background-color: white;
  max-height: 300px;
  width: 250px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0 10px;
  border: solid 1px #C0C0C0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="customSelect">
    <div class="customSelectBox">
      <input type="button" class="customSelectFocus collapsed" value="- Select your options -">
    </div>
    <div class="customSelectList" style="display: none;">
      <div>
        <ul style="list-style-type: none;">
          <li>
            <input type="checkbox">val 1</li>
          <li>
            <input type="checkbox" checked="checked">val 2</li>
          <li>
            <input type="checkbox">val 3</li>
          <li>
            <input type="checkbox">val 4</li>
          <li>
            <input type="checkbox">val 5</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <hr>

  <div class="customSelect">
    <div class="customSelectBox">
      <input type="button" class="customSelectFocus collapsed" value="- Select your options -">
    </div>
    <div class="customSelectList" style="display: none;">
      <div>
        <ul style="list-style-type: none;">
          <li>
            <input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled">val 1</li>
          <li>
            <input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" checked="checked">val 2</li>
          <li>
            <input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" checked="checked">val 3</li>
          <li>
            <input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled">val 4</li>
          <li>
            <input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled">val 5</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should consider using some jQuery plugin for multiselect? 
For example this one https://select2.github.io/examples.html

Comment: I was providing a simple example, but in my real case, it's a tree list